# Auto-update already filled Dropdown list values when source changes

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have created a named range in Sheet1 from A1 to A5 with 5 entries. Using this range, I have created a drop down list in Sheet2 from B1 to B10. Let's say all these values are already filled. Is it possible to update all these values automatically when I change the source in Sheet1? How would I accomplish that?

I tried looking up online but couldn't find much help about this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking in a cell, click on the header (A,B,C, etc) and go to: Data Tools > Data validation.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGHYp.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my issue. Changing my source values doesn't reflect in the already filled cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which must go in the code-behind of Sheet1. The code is commented to explain to you what it is doing but essentially it listens for a single-cell change in Sheet1 column A rows 1 to 5, grabs the old value and then updates the relevant cells in Shee2 to the new value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' do something only if a single cell changes in column A, rows 1 to 5
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <= 5 Then
        ' get the old cell value ... we suspend 'events' while doing this otherwise the call to .Undo will
        ' trigger this procedure again recursively and Excel will crash ... also store the Selection as we
        ' will change it and need to restore it
        Dim vOldCellValue As Variant, vNewCellValue As Variant, rngSel As Range
        If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Set rngSel = Selection
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        vNewCellValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        vOldCellValue = Target.Value
        Target.Value = vNewCellValue
        If Not rngSel Is Nothing Then rngSel.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ' if any cell in the Sheet2 range equals the old value then update it to the new value
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B10")
            If CStr(vOldCellValue) = CStr(cel.Value) Then
                cel.Value = vNewCellValue
            End If
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John,

I pasted this code as it is behind Sheet1 and it doesn't seem to work for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by doesn't work ... do you get an error message (if so, what error number and message and on which line) or does the code not perform as expected (if so, what is it doing, or not doing, that you expected)?